# Coverity. Configure coverity to check that a declared variable is initialized before usage as a pointer

Tags: c, function, coverity

Looking for a way to configure Coverity such that it will ensure that a declared variable on the stack is initialised prior to its address being passed to another function

For example in the code below x is declared on the stack, but it is not initialised and it is therefore indeterminate.
The address of x is then passed to func2. Since the value of x is not defined, the behavior of func2 cannot be certain.

Can Coverity issue a warning for this type of error?

```
void func1(uint32_t* val)
{
    uint32_t x; /*x is not initialised!! */
    func2(val, &x);
}

void func2(uint32_t* val, uint32_t* x)
{
    uint32_t y;
    y = (*x) + (*v);
}
```

Comment: Type fix.... should be y = *val + *x;

Comment: Some functions are perfectly safe when called with a pointer to an uninitialized variable because they treat the variable pointed at as an output parameter and do not attempt to read the uninitialized value.  Other functions, as you demonstrate, read from the pointer passed in and assume that the programmer knows what they're doing and will only pass a pointer to an initialized variable.  There is no direct, declarative way in standard C to distinguish between the two use cases, both of which are valid.  What you request is not always necessary, therefore.

Answer (score 0):

Strange you don't have it, but having UNINIT checker enabled should do the trick.

Check how you execute cov-analyze. You can specify your own checkers configuration there by  --dc-config parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot. There is no online docs. You need to get it from your running     Coverity server. I am glad I don't have to use it anymore :)

Comment: Thanks — if the information is not online, it's sad but there's not much anyone can do about it except use other tools instead.

Comment: I added a higher level of agrressiveness to the coverity analyse with the following command .                                                                                                                             
 cov-analyse --aggressiveness-level high ........                                                                                                                       
  This switched on the UNINIT option. However, this option will only spot an error if an unitialised variable is used. It will not spot an error if a pointer to an unitialised variable is used.

Comment: Allright, then I think, Coverity might be confused by how you specified the parameter x in your function. This may be the case Jonathan Leffler mentioned above. If you would put const qualifier in front of the parameter, it may make Coverity realize it is a parameter and will not be set from within the function call.

Comment: const will work if the pointer is dereferenced only. However we cannot use const if the pointer is both dereferenced and populated i.e. void func2(uint32_t* val, uint32_t* x){ uint32_t y = *x +*val; *x = y;} .... Can coverity be instructed to ensure that x is initialised?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help on this one. The only real solution in this particular case is to ensure that the object is initialised prior to passing its address to a function. i.e. x = 0 in func1 above